# SimpleHtmlDom take elements from pagination built with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, dom, pagination, simple-html-dom

So i already have used SimpleHtmlDom with success. The difference is that i iterated through the pagination based on the url.
For example the domain would be:

www.example.com/articles

and the pagination would be

www.example.com/articles/page/1.html

Now i have a pagination that is based on javascript and i get only the results from the first page. Now, when i tell the page to get to the next page, i assume that it reloads the page, so it goes from the start again because the url does not change.

One extra problem is that the link that belongs to the "next page", if you copy it and paste it on the URL bar then it redirects you to another section of the website. (So much for developers -_- )

I will actually paste the original code so you can see by yourself what is going on with the links.

Anyways my question is the following:

How can i iterate through the whole pagination?

```
<?php 

 require "simple_html_dom.php";
 $url = "http://es.4story.gameforge.com/ranking/browse?type=world";
 $baseUrl = "http://es.4story.gameforge.com/ranking/browse?type=world";
 //Create a DOM object
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 // Load HTML from a URL
 $html->load_file($url);
 // Get all links
 foreach ($html->find('.enc_controls .enc_pager a.enc_next') as $anchor) {
 $tempUrl = $baseUrl . $anchor->href;
 $linkHtml = file_get_html($tempUrl);
 foreach ($linkHtml->find('#results td .item_classWrap a span') as $item ) {
    echo $item;
    echo "<hr/>";
 }  
}
```

Comment: If the content is added to the page using JavaScript then you can't use SimpleHtmlDom to get it.

Comment: maybe any other way to do it?

Comment: Not sure if best solution but have a look at `headless browsers` like `PhantomJS` or `SlimerJS`. I did something similar with SlimerJS.

Comment: The "next links" are actually form posts so you're going to need to at minimum bring curl or guzzle along for this.